# Lookbehind and lookahead regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a strings like this:

> journals/cl/SantoNR90:::Michele Di Santo::Libero Nigro::Wilma
>   Russo:::Programmer-Defined Control Abstractions in Modula-2

I need to capture `Michele Di Santo`, `Libero Nigro`, `Wilma Russo` but not the last one.

This regex matches almost what I need:

```
/(?<=::).*?(?=::)/
```

But it has problem, it captures the third colon

```
str.scan(/(?<=::).*?(?=::)/) #=> [":Michele Di Santo", ...]
```

As you can see, the first match has a colon at the beginning.

How to fix this regex to avoid this third colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression to do that could be:

```
(?<=::)[^:].*?(?=::)
```

Although if the string to be searched is always in the form of "xxx:::A::B::C:::xxx" and you only care about A, B and C, consider using something more specific, and using the capture groups to get A, B and C:

```
:::(.+?)::(.+?)::(.+?):::
```

`$1`, `$2` and `$3` will contain the group matches.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use regex for this. All you need to do is split the input string on `:::`, take the second string from the resulting array, and split that on `::`. Faster to code, faster to run, and easier to read than a regex version.

Edit: The code:

```
str.split(':::')[1].split('::')
```

Running on CodePad: http://codepad.org/1BNNwoh6

Comment: Your decision is simplier and maybe faster but it won't be clean - I have to remove first part, last part, split by '::' than delete ':' - I don't think it's a neat way.

Comment: `your_string.split(":::")[1].split("::")` -- not "that" bad.

Comment: It will be cleaner and neater than the regex version, and string manipulation is usually (not always, but certainly here IMHO) best practice when you have a task that can be done simply without regex.

Comment: Also, you won't have to remove or delete anything. The delimiters will be gone from the results. See the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple `split` because the string is basically a CSV with colons instead of commas:

```
str = 'journals/cl/SantoNR90:::Michele Di Santo::Libero Nigro::Wilma Russo:::Programmer-Defined Control Abstractions in Modula-2'
items = split(':')
str1, str2, str3 = items[3], items[5], items[7]

=> [
      [0] "Michele Di Santo",
      [1] "Libero Nigro",
      [2] "Wilma Russo"
  ]
```

You could also use:

```
str1, str2, str3 = str.split(':').select{ |s| s > '' }[1, 3]
```

If it's possible to have quoted colons, use the CSV module and set your field delimiter to ':'.